# How to correct JPATH_BASE to run PHP script from a directory not root

Tags: php, joomla

I use AcyMailing API script what works very well, but under Joomla root only - like http://example.com/api.php

But if I place the same script to my own directory under same Joomla, let's say /scripts/api.php - I have the Apache error for line 12

```
PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required '/var/www/html/joomla/scripts/includes/defines.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php') in /var/www/html/joomla/scripts/api.php on line 12
```

The confusing part of code is

```
define('_JEXEC', 1);
define('DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);

if (file_exists(dirname(__FILE__) . '/defines.php')) {
 include_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/defines.php';
}

if (!defined('_JDEFINES')) {
 define('JPATH_BASE', dirname(__FILE__));
 require_once JPATH_BASE.'/includes/defines.php';
}
```

where line 12 is

```
 require_once JPATH_BASE.'/includes/defines.php';
```

How to fix the path to allow api.php run not only from Joomla root, but from /scripts/api.php ?

Thanks in advance for any ideas to try.

EDITED - here is full script with JPATH_SITE as recommended - but again an error

```
PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required 'JPATH_SITE/includes/defines.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php') in /var/www/html/joomla/scripts/singlemail.php on line 12
```

May be something is missed in full script below ?

```
<?php

define('_JEXEC', 1);
define('DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);

if (file_exists(dirname(__FILE__) . '/defines.php')) {
 include_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/defines.php';
}

if (!defined('_JDEFINES')) {
 define('JPATH_BASE', dirname(__FILE__));
 require_once JPATH_SITE.'/includes/defines.php';
}

require_once JPATH_SITE.'/includes/framework.php';
$app = JFactory::getApplication('site');


if(!include_once(rtrim(JPATH_ADMINISTRATOR,DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'components'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'com_acymailing'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'helpers'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'helper.php')){
 echo 'This code can not work without the AcyMailing Component';
 return false;
 }
$mailer = acymailing_get('helper.mailer');
$mailer->report = true;
$mailer->trackEmail = true;
$mailer->autoAddUser = false;
$mailer->sendOne(11,'test@example.com');

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use JPATH_SITE

Eg: http://example.com/mysite/api.php

here mysite is sub-folder here you install joomla that time JPATH_BASE having some problem.

Eg: 
1. http://example.com/mysite/api.php
2. http://example.com/api.php

following path will work all place, because JPATH_SITE will find joomla install folder.

require_once JPATH_SITE."/includes/defines.php";

Comment: Hello, your idea seems to be correct, but I have an Apache error again. I published this error and the full script above - please, look at the one, may be something else is missed in a code to read JPATH_SITE ?